# How to edit $PATH on MacOS Catalina (Zsh)?

Tags: macos, zsh, path, macos-catalina

I open terminal and use `echo $PATH`

I get back:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin/
```

I'm confused because my `.zshrc`, `.zsh`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile` all have nothing in it.

I don't have all these, but I enabled hidden folders and files to see if I did.

I looked in the default system's path. `/etc/path` to see if there was something there, but its just the defaults. I'm only worried because the file in there has something to do with remote packets, `rvictl`.

Comment: Check the zsh man page which rc files get sourced and have a look into those. Usually there is a system wide file shipped with the OS.

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to figure out how you set `rvictl`? Because you can change paths in the files you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, your `$path` gets prepopulated in `/etc/zprofile`:

```bsh
% < /etc/zprofile
# System-wide profile for interactive zsh(1) login shells.

# Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zprofile. See zshbuiltins(1)
# and zshoptions(1) for more details.

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

% man path_helper

path_helper(8)            BSD System Manager's Manual           path_helper(8)

NAME
     path_helper -- helper for constructing PATH environment variable

SYNOPSIS
     path_helper [-c | -s]

DESCRIPTION
     The path_helper utility reads the contents of the files in the directories /etc/paths.d and /etc/manpaths.d and appends their contents to the PATH and MANPATH environment vari-
     ables respectively.  (The MANPATH environment variable will not be modified unless it is already set in the environment.)

     Files in these directories should contain one path element per line.

     Prior to reading these directories, default PATH and MANPATH values are obtained from the files /etc/paths and /etc/manpaths respectively.

     Options:

     -c      Generate C-shell commands on stdout.  This is the default if SHELL ends with "csh".

     -s      Generate Bourne shell commands on stdout.  This is the default if SHELL does not end with "csh".

NOTE
     The path_helper utility should not be invoked directly.  It is intended only for use by the shell profile.

Mac OS X                        March 15, 2007                        Mac OS X
```